# IOS post request

Tags: ios7

I have a button 
When it is done click on the request and opens the following window 
when return back to the previous screen and then press the button query is executed with any parameters

This button code

```
- (IBAction)loginClick:(id)sender {
    if ([self.emailTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [self.passwordTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *falseAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please enter your username and password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [falseAlert show];
    } else {
        [spinner startAnimating];
//        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
//        dispatch_async(queue, ^{

            NSString *initialURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.-------"];
            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:initialURL];
            NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&service=%@", self.emailTextField.text, self.passwordTextField.text, @"login"];
            NSData *mastData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            NSString *mastLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",[mastData length]];
            NSError *error;
            request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;

            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:mastLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:mastData];
            NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
            NSError *requestError = NULL;

            responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
            info = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            request = NULL;
           // dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                if ([info[@"success"] isEqualToString:@"false"]) {
                    [self.errorLabel setHidden:FALSE];
                    [spinner stopAnimating];
                    [spinner setHidden:YES];
                } else {

                    DounloadYatseykoViewController *newController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"load"];
                    newController.dataInfo = responseData;
                    [self presentModalViewController:newController animated:YES];
                }

//                
//            });
//        });

    }




    //NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
}
```

So I go back to the previous screen

```
UIViewController *newController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
    [self presentViewController:newController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: ...Sorry, what's the question?
You're doing about 7 different things in 1 IBAction method. You might want to refactor your code a bit to simplify. 
...And you're putting the plain password text directly into a URL?!

Comment: The problem is that when the program starts when you enter the wrong username and password and then an error after you enter the correct data request also performed correctly but when after an incorrect re-enter data requests again performed well and no crashes 

The question is - what could be the problem